# How to insert records of the range in table when I define the range in first table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

Here I have two table, with the name Table A and Table B.

**Table A**:

```
ID    From     To  
-------------------
1     985      992
2     1201     1207
3     1584     1589
```

**Table B**:

```
ID        Numbers
---------------------------
1            985
2            986
3            987
4            988
5            989
6            990
7            991
8            992
9            1201
10           1202
11            1203
12            1204
13            1205
14            1206
```

and the number goes like this. And the table structure as well.

How can such kind of data can be insert. As I define range from 125- 135 in table A, all the number with in this range must be inserted at table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the well wisher for their valuable suggestion. Answer has been solve with using trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert on samplea
FOR INSERT
AS declare @id int, @from bigint, @to bigint, @number bigint;

select @id=i.id from inserted i;
select @from=i.fromnum from inserted i;
select @to=i.tonum from inserted i;

set @number=@from
while @number<=@to
begin
    insert into sampleB (id, numbers) values (@id,@number);
    set @number=@number+1
end
```

Finally the problem is solved. With this inserting data range in table A, data will be automatically inserted in table B with this trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a cursor and while loops,

```
DELCARE @Uid int, @Ustart int, @Uend int, @Ucounter;
DECLARE Ucursor CURSOR  
FOR SELECT * FROM TableA  ;
OPEN vend_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM Ucursor
INTO @Uid,@Ustart,@Uend

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
    SET @Ucounter = @Ustart
    WHILE @Ucounter <> @Uend
       BEGIN
       INSERT INTO TableB
       VALUES (@Ucount) -- Set the identity on for id
       SET @Ucounter += 1
       END
    FETCH NEXT FROM Ucursor
    INTO @Uid,@Ustart,@Uend
END
CLOSE Ucursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is efficient but it works.

```
DECLARE @range INT = (SELECT [To] - [From] FROM @tableA WHERE [Id] = 1)
DECLARE @count INT = 0

WHILE (@count <= @range)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tableB 
        SELECT [From] + @count FROM @tableA
    SET @count = @count + 1
END
```

Comment: values are repeating while i insert for the 2nd time with new records. old values are being repeated

Comment: I see. I didn't know that requirement so i just did the "insert" part. Glad that you came up with an answer.

Comment: Thank you Chester Lim, for your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select from as n, from, to
      from a
      union all
      select n + 1, from, to
      from cte
      where n < to
     )
select n
from cte;
```

To create a table, you can do:

```
with cte as (
      select from as n, from, to
      from a
      union all
      select n + 1, from, to
      from cte
      where n < to
     )
select identity(), n
into b
from cte;
```

Notes:

- I left the column names as you have them without escaping them.  Obviously, `from` and `to` are keywords in SQL.
- If you have a gap of more than 100, you'll want to use the MAXRECURSION option.
- You can insert values just as easily as creating a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @t table(ID int,Froms int,Tos  int)

insert into @t values
(1   , 985   ,  992  )
,(2   , 1201  ,  1207 )
,(3   , 1584  ,  1589 )

declare @table2  table(id int identity(1,1),numbers int)
insert into @table2
select number from @t t
cross apply(
select distinct number from master..spt_values
where number>t.[froms]   and number<=t.tos)ca

select * from @table2
```

Comment: not worked. alys says must define scalar varaible @t

Comment: what version of sql server r u using ?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: can't say. Above script copy-paste is working fine in SQL 2008 and above.